# Firebase hosting Error 503 Varnish cache server

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase hosting to host a small website and since a few hours it is impossible to access it.
Here is the message I get:

> Error 503 Success
> Success
>
> Guru Mediation:
>
> Details: cache-dfw18634-DFW 1519815733 3397807763
>
> Varnish cache server

I'd like to get some advice on how to fix this error.
Especially if you have a way to solve it with Firebase hosting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firebase hosting is down right now. Check out: https://status.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Oh that makes a lot more sense then. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: I'm only getting this issue in ionic when I test the native build, but It's working on localhost. I wonder why?

Comment: Deleted a ton of previous versions thinking that was the problem!  Thanks